# How to improve complex SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a complex SQL query, this is analytics query for conversations from customers of a facebook fanpage, as bellow:

```sql
SELECT
    SeriesTime AS Time,
    FP.PageID AS PageID,
    COALESCE(MAX(FC.Customers), 0) AS Customers,
    COALESCE(MAX(FC.Conversations), 0) AS Conversations,
    COALESCE(MAX(FCM.Conversations), 0) AS UpdatedConversations,
    COALESCE(MAX(Phones), 0) AS Phones,
    COALESCE(MAX(Missed), 0) AS Missed,
    COALESCE(MAX(FCM.MessageTypes), 0) AS MessageConversations,
    COALESCE(MAX(Total), 0) AS TotalMessage,
    COALESCE(AVG(ResponseTime), 0) AS ResponseTime
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES(:Start, :End, :Interval :: INTERVAL) S (SeriesTime)
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PageID FROM FacebookConversations
) FP
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        FCM.PageID,
        DATE_TRUNC(:Trunc, NULLIF(CreatedTime, '')::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+7') AS Time,
        COUNT(DISTINCT FCM.ConversationID) FILTER (WHERE TotalReplied = 0) AS Missed,
        COUNT(DISTINCT FCM.ConversationID) AS Conversations,
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN FCM."type" = 'message' THEN FCM.ConversationID ELSE NULL END) AS MessageTypes,
        COUNT(FCM.ID) AS Total,
        AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ResponseTime)) FILTER (WHERE IsReplied) AS ResponseTime,
        COUNT(DISTINCT PhoneNumber) AS Phones
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            COUNT(IsReplied) FILTER (WHERE IsReplied) OVER (PARTITION BY ConversationID) AS TotalReplied
        FROM (
            SELECT
                ID,
                PageID,
                type,
                ConversationID,
                CreatedTime,
                CreatedTime::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+7' - LAG(CreatedTime::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+7') OVER Ordered AS ResponseTime,
                COALESCE((LAG("from") OVER Ordered <> "from") AND "from" = PageID, FALSE) AS IsReplied
            FROM
                FacebookConversationMessages
            WINDOW Ordered AS (
                PARTITION BY ConversationID ORDER BY CreatedTime::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+7'
            )
        ) FCM
    ) FCM
    LEFT JOIN
        ConversationPhones CP
    ON
        CP.ConversationMessageID = FCM.ID
    GROUP BY
        Time,
        FCM.PageID
) FCM
ON
    FCM.PageID = FP.PageID
AND
    Time >= SeriesTime
AND
    Time < SeriesTime + :Interval :: INTERVAL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        PageID,
        DATE_TRUNC(:Trunc, NULLIF(CreatedTime, '')::TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/GMT+7') AS CreatedAt,
        COUNT(DISTINCT "from") AS customers,
        COUNT(*) AS Conversations
    FROM
        FacebookConversations
    GROUP BY
        CreatedAt,
        PageID,
        Type
) FC
ON
    FC.PageID = FP.PageID
AND
    CreatedAt >= SeriesTime
AND
    CreatedAt < SeriesTime + :Interval :: INTERVAL
WHERE
    FP.PageID = :PageID
GROUP BY
    SeriesTime,
    FP.PageID
ORDER BY
    FP.PageID,
    SeriesTime
```

On my localhost (with fewer data), it run quite fast, and return exactly what I want. But on server, it run very very SLOW. (normally it take about 5 minutes to complete :() Can any one tell me what parts make this SLOW?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query to your question

Comment: How many rows in each table?  Do you really want a `CROSS` join?

Comment: Where's the documentation on `GENERATE_SERIES` in MySQL?